# How to convert a .CSV file to a RINEX file for post-processing?

Tags: convert, gps, rinex

I will preface this by saying i'm not 100% sure this is the right stack exchange to ask this on and i'm completely out of my depths here with the work i'm trying to do but alas i will proceed.

Field staff use a variety of android devices to collect GPS points of water meters but their accuracy is roughly 2-3 meters which isn't good enough.

I want to take the raw GNSS measurements and upload them to AUSPOS or download corrections from CORSNet and post-process them in Emlid Studio.

Currently i'm using GPSTest to record the raw GNSS measurements and im trying to convert them to RINEX so i can use them for post-processing but I can't found a way to convert them. I've done a bunch of googling and asking chat GPT but it's not getting me anywhere.

This is leading me to doubt my limited knowledge on the subject. Am i correct in needing raw GNSS measurements for use in post-processing? Is the log provided by GPSTest what i need for post-processing? Can you convert .csv to RINEX?

I'm not sure how to upload the test file from GPSTest to this question. If someone can advise on how i will upload it for you to look at.

This is the link to my initial question on a different stack exchange which goes into a bit more detail about the devices used and what not. [Link](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/252938/collecting-raw-gnss-data-on-various-android-devices)

Below is a small example of what GPSTest produces.

```
# Version: v3.10.2 (24096-google), Manufacturer: samsung, Model: SM-S908E, GNSS HW Year: 2020, Platform: 13, API Level: 33 
# 
# Raw GNSS measurements format:
#   Raw,utcTimeMillis,TimeNanos,LeapSecond,TimeUncertaintyNanos,FullBiasNanos,BiasNanos,BiasUncertaintyNanos,DriftNanosPerSecond,DriftUncertaintyNanosPerSecond,HardwareClockDiscontinuityCount,Svid,TimeOffsetNanos,State,ReceivedSvTimeNanos,ReceivedSvTimeUncertaintyNanos,Cn0DbHz,PseudorangeRateMetersPerSecond,PseudorangeRateUncertaintyMetersPerSecond,AccumulatedDeltaRangeState,AccumulatedDeltaRangeMeters,AccumulatedDeltaRangeUncertaintyMeters,CarrierFrequencyHz,CarrierCycles,CarrierPhase,CarrierPhaseUncertainty,MultipathIndicator,SnrInDb,ConstellationType,AgcDb,BasebandCn0DbHz,FullInterSignalBiasNanos,FullInterSignalBiasUncertaintyNanos,SatelliteInterSignalBiasNanos,SatelliteInterSignalBiasUncertaintyNanos,CodeType,ChipsetElapsedRealtimeNanos
# 
# Location fix format:
#   Fix,Provider,LatitudeDegrees,LongitudeDegrees,AltitudeMeters,SpeedMps,AccuracyMeters,BearingDegrees,UnixTimeMillis,SpeedAccuracyMps,BearingAccuracyDegrees,elapsedRealtimeNanos,VerticalAccuracyMeters,MockLocation
# 
# Navigation message format:
#   Nav,Svid,Type,Status,MessageId,Sub-messageId,Data(Bytes)
# 
# NMEA format (for [NMEA sentence] format see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NMEA_0183):
#   NMEA,[NMEA sentence],(UTC)TimeInMs
# 
# GnssAntennaInfo format (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/GnssAntennaInfo):
#   GnssAntennaInfo,CarrierFrequencyMHz,PhaseCenterOffsetXOffsetMm,PhaseCenterOffsetXOffsetUncertaintyMm,PhaseCenterOffsetYOffsetMm,PhaseCenterOffsetYOffsetUncertaintyMm,PhaseCenterOffsetZOffsetMm,PhaseCenterOffsetZOffsetUncertaintyMm,PhaseCenterVariationCorrectionsArray,PhaseCenterVariationCorrectionUncertaintiesArray,PhaseCenterVariationCorrectionsDeltaPhi,PhaseCenterVariationCorrectionsDeltaTheta,SignalGainCorrectionsArray,SignalGainCorrectionUncertaintiesArray,SignalGainCorrectionsDeltaPhi,SignalGainCorrectionsDeltaTheta
# 
# GnssStatus format (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/GnssStatus):
#   Status,UnixTimeMillis,SignalCount,SignalIndex,ConstellationType,Svid,CarrierFrequencyHz,Cn0DbHz,AzimuthDegrees,ElevationDegrees,UsedInFix,HasAlmanacData,HasEphemerisData,BasebandCn0DbHz
# Orientation sensor format (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorEvent#values):
#   OrientationDeg,utcTimeMillis,elapsedRealtimeNanos,yawDeg,rollDeg,pitchDeg
OrientationDeg,1693798987882,1284309357162729,180.42104943852348,-38.24424748380113,27.14270730876711
OrientationDeg,1693798987886,1284309361886948,180.59381224338983,-38.122799890169134,27.294527046090863
OrientationDeg,1693798987891,1284309366611167,180.37643464286498,-38.0551366211564,27.614287474726886
OrientationDeg,1693798987896,1284309371335437,181.08770322227338,-38.00293007023541,27.968506207725625
OrientationDeg,1693798987901,1284309376059656,182.02692253504188,-37.96139910498715,28.393332021269373
OrientationDeg,1693798987904,1284309380783875,184.13615325263356,-37.97272014353644,28.908659548863078
OrientationDeg,1693798987910,1284309385508094,185.75490808592656,-38.05835364025548,29.551971161124484
OrientationDeg,1693798987915,1284309390232312,186.2404935547795,-38.199724895696406,30.34054723665372
```

Comment: @user2856 I don't know how to link a test or where to upload it to for people to view. Any ideas? I did see that python rinex converter but i don't know how to use python.